How to properly create a service in Ubuntu?
I have a server with Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS and I need to create a service that would be running on the server. I found this SO answer which details how to create and enable a service, however my service fails with Failed with result 'exit-code'.
These are the steps that I performed to create the service:

sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/scrapyd.service



[Unit]
Description=Scrapyd service
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/projects
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/scrapyd

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target


/home/projects is the directory where are my projects which would use the scrapyd service. The ExecStart - I used the same path as in the "tutorial". If I cd into /usr/local/bin/, there's no scrapyd.

I ran systemctl enable scrapyd.service and the terminal outputted Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/scrapyd.service → /lib/systemd/system/scrapyd.service.

I ran systemctl start scrapyd.service (there was no output)

Finally, I ran systemctl status scrapyd.service and got this error:



× scrapyd.service - Scrapyd service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/scrapyd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2024-04-21 20:43:34 UTC; 41s ago
    Process: 792557 ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/scrapyd (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
   Main PID: 792557 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
        CPU: 2ms

Apr 21 20:43:34 SERVER systemd[1]: Started Scrapyd service.
Apr 21 20:43:34 SERVER systemd[1]: scrapyd.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Apr 21 20:43:34 SERVER systemd[1]: scrapyd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.


What is the proper way to set up a new service on Ubuntu?

The original directions were for Ubuntu 16.04. According to a more recent tutorial in Foss, https://www.fosslinux.com/111815/a-guide-to-creating-linux-services-with-systemd.htm, the script should reside in /usr/local/bin. Also, did you make the script executable? That can be done from Terminal of from a file manager.

See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/490707/1254

Use  journalctl for more details on why it failed. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-journalctl-to-view-and-manipulate-systemd-logs.  Your service is best put in /etc/systemd/system.

What is the proper way to set up a new service on Ubuntu?

Any service that you create (i.e. one that is not installed by a package, for example) should go in /etc/systemd/system/
After creating or changing the service, you must run systemctl daemon-reload.
Normally, if your service is failing, there are two main ways of troubleshooting it (in my opinion):

Run journalctl -u [your_service] to show logs for the service. This may or may not show something useful.
Attempt to run whatever is specified as ExecStart= manually as the user specified by User=. By default and if not specified, this will be root.



In your case, the answer is pretty simple since you yourself say that:

If I cd into /usr/local/bin/, there's no scrapyd.

So you are attempting to start a service pointing at a file that does not exist.
If the scrapyd exists somewhere else, you can probably change the ExecStart= directive to match, and if it's not installed you need to install it -- which is not a systemd issue.

if it 'normally' runs - which scrapyd is probably helpful.

@JourneymanGeek what do you mean "if it normally runs"?

If you can run the scrapyd command from the terminal - which is generally something to test before writing a systemd service with said command
